# SPARQL to a Named Graph in Jena SDB

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki, named-graphs

I want to query my Apache Jena triplestore with SPAQRL. Let's assume there is a named graph "namedGraph" in my dateset. Now I query with the following SPAQRL:

```
SELECT ?src ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE{
    GRAPH ?src{
        ?subject ?predicate ?object
    }
}
```

and i get the whole model with `<namedGraph>` as `?src` value. So far, everything is fine, but when I use this SPARQL:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE{
    GRAPH <namedGraph>{
        ?subject ?predicate ?object
    }
}
```

there is no result. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it was a mistake. I gave my Model a normal name - `namedGraph`. If you don't provide an `URI` like `http://example/namedGraph` Apache Jena initializes this graph with the following default `URI`: `http://server/unset-base/namedGraph`.